# GCP Datastore with ndb: filter with ndb.OR

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have a entity in my datastore called Group, the groups have owners and managers. Those are another entity called Member. It has an email property.

I want to make a query, using ndb, to retrieve all the groups the member is manager or owner (or both).

What I do is (after retrieving the user)

```
Group.query().filter(ndb.OR(Group.owners == member.key, Group.managers == member.key)).fetch(projection=Group.projection)
```

And this does not return all the groups I expect. Am I misusing the `ndb.OR` operator ?

Thanks for helping

Comment: what is `Group.projection`?

Comment: I only want to retrieve some properties of my Group objects. (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/projectionqueries)

Comment: Would you be able to describe a bit more about "And this does not return all the groups I expect"?  Are you writing an entity then doing the query and expecting the entity that was very recently written, if so then you might be hitting eventual consistency (https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/articles/balancing-strong-and-eventual-consistency-with-google-cloud-datastore/#eventual-consistency-in-cloud-datastore).

Comment: If you are using a projection query where the projected value is different from the query filter then you'll need a composite index for each member of your ndb.OR.  OR is implemented entirely on the client side, so I don't know off hand what ndb does if one query fails but the other succeeds.